# storing and retrieving GPS value in SQLIte3

Tags: sqlite, mojolicious

I want to store the GPS values like latitude, longitude, and timestamp value in `SQLITE3`. my schema is like `REAL` for latitude and longitude and `DATETIME` for timestamp value.

It was inserted successfully. but when i try to retrieve it show the server error as,

```
Can't locate DateTime/Format/SQLite.pm in @INC
```

how to store the timestamp value in SQLite3 database which is the best datatype to store these values. i want to do some computations with that timestamp like time delay etc..

Any useful help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can store the timestamp in [Unix Time](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time) such as :

```
SELECT strftime('%s', 'now');
```

Will return something like this : `1367641852`

The result will represent the number of seconds passed since `January 1, 1970`.

So you can easily subtract two different timestamps and get the number of seconds as delay between two different times.

Also you should change your schema for timestamp to `INTEGER`.

Answer (score 0):

SQLite3 doesn't have a DATETIME format. Instead it has datetime functions. See the documentation [here](http://sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html).

A popular option is to store datetime as a string in ISO format

```
YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS.SSS
```

The advantage is that these strings sort in the correct order.

You can also store datetimes as numbers in SQLite's [Julian Day](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Julian_day) format or as Unix TIme as semihyagcioglu suggested.